# How do I uninstall Norton 360?

Tags: uninstall, norton-360

It keeps popping up with the update to make it windows ten compatible and it interrupts whatever im doing, and I've even tried caving and updating it and that doesn't work. I'm just getting rid of the whole thing but I've already tried removing it via the Norton remover tool and that doesn't work, what can I do? I am fine if the solution delves into regedit. Norton has a security feature to basically make it unable to install the thing, does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: You tried uninstalling all components of it from Control Panel > Programs and features > Uninstall a program ???

Comment: @MPineda Yes, that was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Try logging in with safe mode and then uninstalling it.
also try https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/kb20080710133834EN_EndUserProfile_en_us

Comment: An unclean way to do it would be to boot up a live CD (Windows or Linux are both fine) and remove the Program Files folder.

Comment: @mousomer As far as I know even in safe mode you can't just simply uninstall it, It is to prevent malware from uninstalling the security software. Logical but that remover tool you linked me to is the thing I already tried.

Comment: try this one:
http://norton-removal-tool.en.softonic.com/

worked for me.